# WiFi voucher configuration using c#

Tags: c#, captiveportal

I am now working with a hotspot manager application in c#, and i am stock with the voucher creation.Most routers nowadays have built in captive portal. My Problems is how to add new vouchers with time limit to the router using c#. Can somebody help on this I am really lost at the momment. thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a great question but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow